# JavaFX project play youtube videos

Tags: youtube, javafx

I work on an automatically music player. To be short, i use the Last.fm api to get a lot of tracks names and tags. Using these tags and some intelligence computing algorithms, once you play a track, the player sets another track (with tags very appropriate to the tags of the track listened before).

I used the youtube API to search for the URL's of the movies, and I managed to make it work. Now I want to make the videos play on my music player. I have tried to place the youtube player on WebView. It works, but not as intended. I want to control that player. I want it to start playing automatically, and I want to get noticed when the video ended so I can start the next one.

Any clues of what should I do to play the videos from youtube based on the search that uses the Youtube API, and to have control over the youtube player that I place on my GUI(make it play and stop from command line)? Or is there any possible way do download the youtube movie and play it using the JavaFX API? I searched google and noticed I cannot download  youtube movie into a format that can be played by JavaFX api.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Nicolae Mariuta! Although you did describe your problem, it is greatly appreciated to be able to see some code. Consider adding some code so that your question will have a much higher value

Comment: Consider descoping your questions a little bit so they just ask one specific thing (and demo your current attempts or research to solve that thing).  For example, playing back a YouTube from JavaFX is one thing for one question, using search with the YouTube API is a completely different thing and utilizing the YouTube playback API from external code is another different thing.

Answer (score 3):

*Update Dec 4th, 2015*

Some versions of JavaFX 8 are unable to play back youtube video content.  Currently, for instance, Java 8u66 cannot playback youtube video content, but Java 8u72 early access release can.

Also note some of the videos referenced in the sample solution are no longer available or are protected from play in embedded video players.  So ensure that you perform any tests using available and videos that have not been distribution restricted.  Refer to the youtube documentation for information on distribution restriction if need be.

> Any clues of what should I do to play the videos from youtube

As a hints to get you started, see [code playing YouTube videos in JavaFX](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374) and the [YouTube HTML5 api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference).

Here is the sample code I linked running and playing YouTube videos back within a JavaFX WebView with some (very minimal) control over the video playback via interaction with a JavaFX "New Song" button.

[image: slideoutyoutubeplayer]

> Or is there any possible way do download the youtube movie and play it using the JavaFX API? I searched google and noticed I cannot download youtube movie into a format that can be played by JavaFX api.

I think such a usage would violate [YouTube's terms of service](http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=GB&template=terms).  I believe YouTube requires you to play the video back using the YouTube video player (let's them insert ads in the video player etc).

> 5.1 A
>
> you agree not to distribute any part of or parts of the Website or the
>   Service, including but not limited to any Content, in any medium
>   without YouTube's prior written authorisation, unless YouTube makes
>   available the means for such distribution through functionality
>   offered by the Service (such as the YouTube Player);
>
> 5.1 C
>
> you agree not to access Content through any technology
>   or means other than the video playback pages of the Website itself,
>   the YouTube Player, or such other means as YouTube may explicitly
>   designate for this purpose;

Comment: Do you have any luck I am trying to play local swf files in JavaFX but it seems that It does not allows to load Flash player

Comment: Playing SWF files is not a matter of luck.  I have never tried it because I know it would not work.  SWF is a Flash specific format that is not supported by JavaFX and never will be.  This answer has nothing to do with SWF, it is about playing YouTube videos using YouTube's HTML5 API (not the YouTube Flash API).

Comment: Is there any possibility that I can play my local swf content inside a webview hosting flash player? I mean it it's possible so please guide me. I just want to play local swf files even by using flash player but how !!!

Comment: No AZ, you cannot play SWF content in a WebView.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking your time and replying me. Dear is it possible for you to give me some reference so that I can present it to my manager.

Comment: Sure AZ, here is a [quote by Richard Bair (JavaFX project lead)](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2311093): `As for plugins, we are not likely to ever support running plugins (except maybe applets), for security reasons.`

Answer (score 1):

I advanced  little, but I got stuck to other problems.

First of all, the code from jewelsea  was great. Now I could embed the player into a secondary window of my player and it shows the movie based on the URL that i got using the youtube api.  But it looks like JavaFX cannot show most of the movies. It  shows me the youtube player and an error message saying that I need to install latest version of Adobe Flashplayer.  From my research, I noticed that the webView can only show movies with quality set at 240p, not higher.

I have searched a lot on Google how to make my webView to play the 240p quality video. First of all, i tried to set the youtube query parameters (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters#formatsp). I tried all the parameters from there: 1,5 and 6. But yet, I did not get the URL of movie with format that can be viewed on the webView of the JavaFX.

I also tried to embed the video quality in the URL of the movie like this: 
http:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=og2YZlLhjKs&vq=small:240p ; but it does not work at all. I also wrote that URL in the browser and it looks like the youtube automatically sets the video to the highest quality, no matter what parameter I write in the URL.

The youtube api code that I used is the same like in this webpage: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/05/getting-started-with-youtube-java-api.html

I just moved the main class code to a method that returns the URL of the first video that is in the list, and I changed the " query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.VIEW_COUNT); "
to  "  query.setOrderBy(YouTubeQuery.OrderBy.RELEVANCE);". And this works fine, it shows the url to proper music videos that I search.

I am sorry for not showing the code of my project but it is big and it contains 2-3 api keys, and if you tell me how to change the video URL http:/www.youtube.com/watch?v=og2YZlLhjKs to work on the code from this website: https:/gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374 , then I will know that to do to make it work on my project as well;

And the thing about  YouTube playback API also enlightened me. I see that API has a lot of functions that could help me to play a lot easier with the video content (make it play, make it stop) but the problem is that I do not have knowledge about javascript programming and it is very sad that I do not have those methods in Java API as well. Maybe I will give it a try and insert javascript code into my webview. But, if I edit the webview using javascript... Is it going to play higher quality movies on the JavaFX webView?